# Насколько юзабельна моя функция суммы цифр числа?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

```
public static int SumCountNum(int k)
        {
            int result = 0;
            string ish = Convert.ToString(k);
            foreach(char a in ish)
            {
                result = result + Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(a));
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Так то все работает, просто хотелось бы узнать, можно ли как-нибудь заменить мои костыли и насколько правильно их использовать?

Comment: Что будете делать с отрицательными числами?

Comment: Конечно конвертировать число в строку, строку в символы, символ в строку, строку в число чтобы сложить цифры - неэффективно

Comment: а вот кстати да, спасибо, так то придется вызывать функцию с модулем числа

Comment: можно ведь небось в ASCII строку конвертировать, и убрать эти конвертации символов для сложения, а просто коды складывать, за вычетом индекса единицы

Comment: @teran зачем, если есть классическое решение, оно самое эффективное и без лишних приседаний с памятью/конвертациями

Comment: @tym32167 ни за чем, я к тому, что даже со строковым подходом, тут многовато конвертаций.

Comment: @teran а, ну это да, можно просто `'0'` вычитать из символов да складывать

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Классическое решение, в котором сильно меньше накладные расходы:

```
while (k != 0)
{
  result += k % 10;
  k /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Только у отрицательного числа результат тоже будет отрицательным.